# Which set of python libraries i should learn for AI and Data mining stuff

Tags: python, django, statistics, data-mining

I am learning python and django. I need to do extensive stuff for data parsing , stats , AI and data mining. There are many libraries available. so I want to know which SET I should learn. Currently I have the following SET in My Mind.

- Parsing: Beautiful Soup
- Search Engine: Whoosh  (Will it crawl and index the website or not??)
- AI: PyBrain
- Data Mining: orange (I am not sure bout this, Anything else)

So I want to know is there anything else which I need to learn for that fields.
Or Some libraries which someone has tried. basically I want libraries which i can use from inside Django , I don't want different frameworks for those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the scikit cited by @aix, you might want to take a look at the following libraries:

- [mlpy](https://mlpy.fbk.eu/), an ML library for preprocessing, clustering, predictive classification, regression and feature selection.
- [PyML](http://pyml.sourceforge.net/), yet another ML library.
- [pandas](http://code.google.com/p/pandas/) (Pythonic cross-section, time series, and statistical analysis), is a set of fast NumPy-based data structures optimized for panel, time series, and cross-sectional data analysis, with an emphasis on econometric applications.
- [scikits.statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/), implements common statistical model (OLS/GLS, GLM, M-estimators, etc.). I really like this package, the syntax is clean and it feels like we didn't leave R.

I'll really second investigating orange capabilities which is a full-featured application for data mining, but you can call it from external scripts, see e.g. the [Beginning with Orange](http://orange.biolab.si/doc/ofb-rst/index.html) tutorial to get an idea.

Answer (score 2):

I find your requirements a little vague, but you might want to take a look at [`scikits.learn`](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. I was looking exactly for this :)